# How to Generate Dynamic variable In PHP

Tags: php

Generate N number of varible based of my array length in PHP.

```
for($i; $i<n; $i++){

//varible should be there and should be unique on every index.

}
```

Comment: [The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. This can lead to frustration by people who are trying to help you solve the problem because by the time you ask about it, the solution that you need help with might not have any obvious connections to the problem that you are trying to solve.
To avoid falling into this trap, always include information about a broader picture along with any attempted solution.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: what is this  ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This

```
for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){

 ${'Name'.$i} = "10$i";

}
```

On every time when loop executed **$i** value will be changed
if n = 2

then Variable should be

```
$Name0 = "100";
$Name1 = "101";
```

Comment: The most useless answer on Stack Overflow

Comment: You don't even understand the code you wrote, it will be 10.0, not 100

Comment: @YourCommonSense Even You dont understand the code, beacuse i also missed to initiate $i = 0 and put wrong variable formate only n. You didnt get it . Noob